# Function to subset dataframe on optional arguments

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
   Country = c("France", "England", "India", "America", "England"),
   City = c("Paris", "London", "Mumbai", "Los Angeles", "London"),
   Order_No = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
   delivered = c("Yes", "no", "Yes", "No", "yes"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

and multiple other columns as well (around 50)

I want to write a function which is generic and can take in as many parameters as the user wants and return a subset of only those specific columns. So the user should technically be able to pass 1 column or 30 columns to get the result back from function

With what I was able to find online on optional arguments, I wrote this following code but I am running into issues. Can anyone help me out here?

```
SubsetFunction <- function(inputdf, ...)
{
      params <- vector(...)
      subset.df <- subset(inputdf, select = params)
      return(subset.df)
}
```

This is the error I am getting -

> error in vector(...) : 
>         vector: cannot make a vector of mode 'Country'.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to use `dplyr::select()` ? It seems to have all the functionality you are trying to implement.

Comment: Simply use `df[df$Country %in% selection, ]` where selection are the countries to be selected, e.g. `c("France", "England")`. For several criteria use, e.g.,  `df[df$Country %in% selection & df$delivered == "no", ]`

Comment: See that your example data frame has a problem in the columns 'delivered'.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I would like to call my function like this : output.df <- SubsetFunction (df, "Country", "delivered") or output.df <- SubsetFunction (df, "Country", "delivered", "City").  How do I use the suggestions you have given? I am not able to figure it out

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error @Ozan147

Comment: Why is simply using `base::subset` not sufficient? Why setting up a new function?

Comment: @ManuelBickel I am creating a package with custom error logging messages, hence, I am trying to move certain parts of my code into functions which will in line with the rest of my code structure. Yes, I realize that I am just trying to replicate the base subset here; but the justification is what I have said above. Maybe I need not attempt it for this case. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `vector(...)` is making problems here. The ellipsis has to be converted into a list instead. Therefore, in order to finally obtain a vector out of the three-dot parameters, the seemingly awkward construction `unlist(list(...))` should be used instead of `vector(...)`:

```
SubsetFunction <- function(inputdf, ...){
  params <- unlist(list(...))
  subset.df <- subset(inputdf, select=params)
  return(subset.df)
}
```

This allows to call the function `SubsetFunction()` with an arbitrary number of parameters:

```
> SubsetFunction(df1, "City")
#         City
#1       Paris
#2      London
#3      Mumbai
#4 Los Angeles
#5      London
> SubsetFunction (df1, "City", "delivered")
#         City delivered
#1       Paris       Yes
#2      London        no
#3      Mumbai       Yes
#4 Los Angeles        No
#5      London       yes
```

Comment: wow! @RHertel, thank you so much for the explanation and code snippet. It solves my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `missing` function here to check if arguments are present or not

```
select_cols <- function(df, cols) {
   if(missing(cols))
      df
   else
      df[cols]
}

select_cols(df1, c("Country", "City"))

#  Country        City
#1  France       Paris
#2 England      London
#3   India      Mumbai
#4 America Los Angeles
#5 England      London

select_cols(df1)

#   Country        City Order_No delivered
#1  France       Paris        1       Yes
#2 England      London        2        no
#3   India      Mumbai        3       Yes
#4 America Los Angeles        4        No
#5 England      London        5       yes
```

Comment: Thanks @Ronak for your comment!